# How to intall ssl support for Nikto scanner?? I am trying install ssl library dependencies.Help me to achieve it

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, ubuntu-12.04, cpan, penetration-testing

I have installed nikto on ubuntu 12.04 .when i am trying to scan targets oves ssl .It is sayin no SSL supoort .Please help me confgure nikto .
On nikto website below line is written ,but not explained.help me configure it

For SSL support the Net::SSLeay Perl module must be installed.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

Debian / Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install perl libnet-ssleay-perl openssl libauthen-pam-perl libio-pty-perl libmd5-perl
```

CentOS / Fedora:

```
yum install openssl-devel perl perl-Net-SSLeay perl-Crypt-SSLeay
```

Comment: `libnet-ssleay-perl` was the missing library in my case (Ubuntu 14.04 release)

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted seems old. I have encountered same issue while using Nikto2 https://github.com/sullo/nikto in Ubuntu 20.04.5.

[image]

I could resolve the issue by running

> sudo apt-get install perl libnet-ssleay-perl openssl
> libauthen-pam-perl libio-pty-perl

[image]